# Why do I lose focus and direction in my songwriting?

Tags: poetry, grammar, sentence-structure, lyrics, clarity

Today while writing my song, every line seemed to fight me.  It seemed to wander without direction. I  don't always have this problem but would like to figure how to avoid writing songs that wind up aimless. Does it have to do with sentence structure, or what am I doing wrong?

.

Comment: Outline. Develop a narrative arc where a character or situation changes or is revealed. Consider how your narrative voice effects the message. Edit until you get there.

Comment: It's a 24-line poem. Yes there is room for some sort of development or reveal. Narrative arcs are tricks to keep readers (and writers) focused and interested. You say this is your problem.

Comment: Your piece has 2 parts so before/after or some duality is logical: start with a question, end with an answer… Give an incomplete picture, then a 'twist'… Expectation vs reality…  Innocent, then not-so-innocent – If it was 3 parts then a progression is logical. My observation is there is not enough here to be a 'vignette', and what is being communicated is unclear. The advice seems contradictory (is the answer 'on the road' or 'within'? Are they 'in a rut' or endlessly searching? Are they misunderstood, or confessing?) Some context might help… A little more *tableau vivant*, less *zen koan*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who said it had to be structured?

Sometimes, you start of at place A and end at place B...

Sometimes, fun happens.

Take a walk, or do some other activity.

When I am stuck, I watch sport, train, or take a long walk.

Your subconscious has the solution, but the ego might just be in the way.

*And always have somewhere to write down the clues to the solution...*

Comment: The song is deep. Sometimes You want to make cake, but You don't have the ingredients, and then You have to wait... But You still have to make food. Make a new song, and try again. Else You end up editing the song to dead.